# Add script to LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift

Is there any way to add script to my `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file in a similar way to connecting UI elements from `Main.storyboard` to the `ViewController.swift` file? I want to create a loading bar that will change its value, but on the launch screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot add code to the launch screen. This is because the app is still launching at this point thus, you would have no access to do anything until the app has launched (which is when the launch screen disappears).